# Higher Order Interaction. 3 or 4 or 7 way interactions. How to use them in model?

Tags: categorical-data, feature-selection, interaction, boosting

http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/webbooks/logistic/chapter2/

This above website gives an example about using interaction effect between variables. Interacting variables are multiplied and used in the model.However I have read on Kaggle on using 3 or 4-way interaction effect. I use Xgbfi to find interactions but how do I use it in model ?

I have read on kaggle about hashing , bayesian coding and other few techniques. Kindly elaborate on using such 3 or 4-way interaction of Categorical and Numerical variables in my model. Example codes using Python or R is also highly welcomed.

Comment: Using high order interactions is generally not advisable. It is not likely that you can show improvement over lower order models.

Comment: I understand that using such interactions may not be much useful but however still would like to know on how to use them. Any resources or codes to read on those lines is most welcomed.